# Samba 4.9.1 Password sync with CentOS7 root Password

Tags: compilation, passwords, centos7, samba

#### What I NEED

1. Change root's password by using `passwd`
2. samba password sync with root new password, automatically.

P.S. Change from CentOS password to Samba password, **but NOT the opposite**.

#### Base Environment

- OS: CentOS7
- Samba Version: 4.9.1
- Deployment: Source Compilation

#### Source Compilation of Samba

```
chmod 777 samba-4.9.1.tar.gz
tar -zxf samba-4.9.1.tar.gz
cd samba-4.9.1
./configure --without-ad-dc --sbindir=/usr/sbin/  --sysconfdir=/etc/samba/ --mandir=/usr/share/man/
make -j 4
sudo make install
```

P.S. No AD DC, No LDAP Password

#### smb.conf

```
[global]
    workgroup = WORKGROUP
    security = user

    passdb backend = tdbsam

    server signing = mandatory
    client signing = required

[chenjian]
    comment = CHENJIAN Directories
    path = /home/chenjian
    guest ok = no
    browseable = yes
    writable = yes
```

#### What I had TRY

- [samba sync password with unix password on debian wheezy](https://superuser.com/questions/478521/samba-sync-password-with-unix-password-on-debian-wheezy)
- - Neither `libpam-winbind` or `libpam-smbpass` can be found in CentOS7;
- - Change the file of `/etc/pam.d/system-auth`, like:

    ```
    password   requisite**  pam_unix.so nullok obscure min=4 max=8 md5
    password   required   pam_smbpass.so nullok use_authtok try_first_pass
    ```

but there is NO `pam_smbpass.so` in CentOS7 after souce compiling.

- [Encrypted Passwords](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/System_Administration_Guide/Configuring_a_Samba_Server-Encrypted_Passwords.html)
- - By using the shell of `samba-4.9.1/source3/script/mksmbpasswd.sh`
- - `smb.conf` using `passdb backend = smbpasswd`
- - Add `smb passwd file = /etc/samba/smbpasswd`

But,

1. HOW to change the file of `smbpasswd` automatically?
2. There is NO `pam_smbpass.so`, either.

Comment: You are specifically asking about root. Are you able to get non-root users to automatically sync?

Comment: @UncleCarl Sorry, I am not able to do that. Maybe you can write a **SCRIPT** to monitor the changing of non-root password, and then to sync the samba password?

Comment: Yep, this is very frustrating. It shouldn't be difficult, but there doesn't seem to be any definitive guide for using the Linux credentials. I was able to get my smbpasswd to update the Linux password, but I'm giving up and just going with separate credentials.

Comment: Yes, in fact, even for security reasons, we should use different passwords. But such password-sync things meet certain needs.